# uniform distribution from 0 to 1/2

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What is the probability density function of a continuous uniform distribution from 0 to 1/2, because it is supposed to be $f(x) = \frac{1}{1/2 - 0} = 2$ when $x$ $\in$ $[0,1/2]$, but the probability has to be between 0 and 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is the density function. It is not actually the probabilities! Let $X$ has density function $f$, as given in your post

$P(X\leq x) = \int^x_0 2 \text{d}y$. This is always $\leq1$ for $x\leq 1/2$

note for a continuous distribution,

$P(X=x) =0$

Comment: So is the probability density function the density function?

Comment: @kolonel yes, sir!

Comment: And, unlike probability, which is a pure number, probability density is generally a dimensioned quantity, whose dimensions are the reciprocal dimensions of the random variable; its numeric value depends on the size of the unit of measurement. If your variable $X$ is a length, measured in feet, then your probability density is $2$ per foot, which is the same as $1/6$ per inch or $10560$ per mile. Obviously, then, the probability density being numerically greater than or less than $1$ has no great significance.

Comment: @bof i never thought like this before on this elementary issue... Nice!

Answer (score 1):

A probability density function is not a probability.  The meaning of probability density is frequently misunderstood, because students mistakenly try to draw an analogy between continuous and discrete distributions.

The value of a probability density function of a continuous random variable $X$ at a particular point $x$ represents the instantaneous rate of change in the probability of observing $\Pr[X \le x]$.  Somewhat informally, we can write $$f_X(x) \approx \frac{1}{\Delta x} \Pr[x < X \le x + \Delta x];$$ that is, it is the chance of observing $X \in (x, x + \Delta x]$ divided by the width of the interval $\Delta x$, for very small $\Delta x$.  This relationship becomes exact as we take the limit as $\Delta x \to 0$.

For continuous random variables, only statements about the cumulative distribution function have a direct interpretation as probabilities.  The integral of a probability density function over its support must equal $1$.

To summarize:  **a probability density is not itself a probability.**  Only by integrating a density function over some subset of its support do we obtain a corresponding probability, which is the probability of observing the value of the random variable in that subset; i.e., for any event $\mathcal A \subseteq \mathcal S$, $$\Pr[X \in \mathcal A] = \int_{x \in \mathcal A} f_X(x) \, dx.$$  As such, it is entirely possible that the density function can exceed $1$ for some points.  However, a density cannot be less than zero.